# Load Xib Files with NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I've a Custom View in MainMenu.xib which will contains 2 subviews. These subviews should be loaded from some xib files which have a single NSView.
How can i do this?
The Classes that contains IBOutlet and IBActions for each xib from which class should inherit? And for each xib i must set the file owner to the Class that contains outlet/actions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your custom view or main menu's header file should #include the 2 subviews that you mention, and you should list them as IBOutlet members and IBOutlet properties. (don't forget to synthesize!)

In your xib file, you should be able to drag in 2 NSView's and then set their class to your 2 subclasses, and then link them by dragging from 'file's owner' to the object in the 'objects' list.

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained it well... I want to load 2 NSViews from xib files in the MainMenu.xib (created by xcode). This mainMenu.xib contains an NSView, where i want to load the 2 previously mentioned xib. I'm developing for mac

Comment: Also i would to know the best/correct way to link a class with Outlets/Actions to a xib file (and see them in IB). Should i set my custom class in the File's Owner or drag a NSObject (from IB's Object Library)?

Comment: Your 1st comment: Yep, I wrote UIView instead of NSView... but they're  basically the same and what I wrote should still be valid. 2nd comment: As your subclasses inherit from NSView, if you drag an NSView object into Interface Builder and then set their class to those of your subclasses (on the identity inspector tab) then they should work fine. Of course, you'll still have to init them in the loadView: (or similar) method of your main menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
- (BOOL)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName
               owner:(id)owner
     topLevelObjects:(NSArray * _Nonnull *)topLevelObjects
```

to load your xib file, the topLevelObjects parameter is an Array passed by reference, after calling the function it will contain the array of objects from your xib, what you are interested in here is an object of type NSView, you can add the view to wherever you want